# Insert rows into pandas DataFrame while maintaining column data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

What's the best way to insert new rows into an existing pandas DataFrame while maintaining column data types and, at the same time, giving user-defined fill values for columns that aren't specified?  Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Bob', 'Sue', 'Tom'],
    'age': [45, 40, 10],
    'weight': [143.2, 130.2, 34.9],
    'has_children': [True, True, False]
})
```

Assume that I want to add a new record passing just `name` and `age`.  To maintain data types, I can copy rows from `df`, modify values and then append `df` to the copy, e.g.

```
columns = ('name', 'age')
copy_df = df.loc[0:0, columns].copy()
copy_df.loc[0, columns] = 'Cindy', 42
new_df = copy_df.append(df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But that converts the `bool` column to an object.

Here's a really hacky solution that doesn't feel like the "right way" to do this:

```
columns = ('name', 'age')
copy_df = df.loc[0:0].copy()

missing_remap = {
    'int64': 0,
    'float64': 0.0,
    'bool': False,
    'object': ''
}
for c in set(copy_df.columns).difference(columns)):
    copy_df.loc[:, c] = missing_remap[str(copy_df[c].dtype)]

new_df = copy_df.append(df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
new_df.loc[0, columns] = 'Cindy', 42
```

I know I must be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found, since `NaN` is a `float`, adding `NaN` to a series may cause it to be either upcasted to `float` or converted to `object`. You are right in determining this is not a desirable outcome.

There is no straightforward approach. My suggestion is to store your input row data in a dictionary and combine it with a dictionary of defaults before appending. Note that this works because `pd.DataFrame.append` accepts a `dict` argument.

In Python 3.6, you can use the syntax `{**d1, **d2}` to combine two dictionaries with preference for the second.

```
default = {'name': '', 'age': 0, 'weight': 0.0, 'has_children': False}

row = {'name': 'Cindy', 'age': 42}

df = df.append({**default, **row}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)

   age  has_children   name  weight
0   45          True    Bob   143.2
1   40          True    Sue   130.2
2   10         False    Tom    34.9
3   42         False  Cindy     0.0

print(df.dtypes)

age               int64
has_children       bool
name             object
weight          float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Downvoters care to comment? I'm more than happy to edit / update / clarify if there are serious shortcomings.

Comment: Yep, not sure why anybody would downvote this.  You reduced my mess of code into something much easier to follow ...

Comment: What!!!!! Is this answer for this question! No wonder someone downvoted this answer. Replacing missing values in a column to False, just to make it boolean type. As mentioned in the question itself, not the right way! Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Also, pandas itself convert an object column to bool by casting `np.nan` to `True` 
. Why did you chose False as default value?

Comment: My original question asked how to replace NA values with **user-defined** values.  The point was that the user got to choose what made sense for their use-case.  In my case, `False` made sense for the column I was trying to fill.

Comment: @VenkataGogu, I think you missed the point. This isn't just "to make it Boolean" - it's also because OP has **specified default values**.

Comment: @jpp, Got your point! But in OP, it is also mentioned **doesn't feel like the right way**, there are lot of hacky ways to do this. For ex: `df['has_children'] = df['has_children'].fillna(False).astype('bool')`

Comment: @grovduck, yes you are correct. But, don't you feel the weight should not be 0.0? I would like to mention the advantage of keeping the value unchanged, instead of imputing null values to some default values.

Answer (score 2):

It's because, NaN value is a float, but True and False are bool. There are mixed dtypes in one column, so Pandas will automatically convert it into object.

Another instance of this is, if you have a column with all integer values and append a value with float, then pandas change entire column to float by adding '.0' to the remaining values.

---

**Edit**

Based on comments, Another hacky way to convert object to bool dtype.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Bob', 'Sue', 'Tom'],
    'age': [45, 40, 10],
    'weight': [143.2, 130.2, 34.9],
    'has_children': [True, True, False]
})
row = {'name': 'Cindy', 'age': 12}
df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
df['has_children'] = df['has_children'].fillna(False).astype('bool')
```

**Now the new dataframe looks like this :**

```
    age has_children    name    weight
 0  45  True             Bob    143.2
 1  40  True             Sue    130.2
 2  10  False            Tom    34.9
 3  12  False            Cindy  NaN
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  Sorry, I wasn't more clear - I did understand *why* these columns were changing data type, but wanted the best way to avoid this.  It seems like the NaNs need to be dealt with before doing the append?

Comment: Yes, `np.nan` need to be dealt and usually it depends on the use case you are working on. If you are a Data Scientist, then then values have a huge impact on final results. I suggest keeping it as a object and maintaining a schema for later purposes.