# Pandas dataframe with dynamically built columns, and integer data with NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have seen [Insert rows into pandas DataFrame while maintaining column data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650850/insert-rows-into-pandas-dataframe-while-maintaining-column-data-types), and I am aware that

> since NaN is a float, adding NaN to a series may cause it to be either upcasted to float or converted to object.

... but I cannot really tell from those posts whether there is a solution to my use case:

So, I want to dynamically build a pandas DataFrame, starting from one defined column, then add further columns - all with integer data; because of this, clearly some row values will be undefined, that is, NaN. Here is a brief example:

```
import pandas as pd
print("pandas.__version__ {}".format(pd.__version__))

# initialize dataframe with one column
test_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["time"])

# "append column" - add data with a newly defined column
test_df = test_df.append({'time': 20, 'varA': 14}, ignore_index=True)

# (same)
test_df = test_df.append({'time': 5673547, 'varB': 78}, ignore_index=True)

# (same)
test_df = test_df.append({'time': 9480530495459073, 'varC': 4567457}, ignore_index=True)

print(test_df)
print(test_df.astype(pd.Int64Dtype()))
```

This prints:

```
pandas.__version__ 1.0.2
          time  varA  varB       varC
0           20  14.0   NaN        NaN
1  5.67355e+06   NaN  78.0        NaN
2  9.48053e+15   NaN   NaN  4567457.0
               time  varA  varB     varC
0                20    14  <NA>     <NA>
1           5673547  <NA>    78     <NA>
2  9480530495459072  <NA>  <NA>  4567457
```

So, while I can somewhat get around this by building the DataFrame as a float, then cast it to integer - notice that I've specified 9480530495459073 - and yet, after cast, I get 9480530495459072 printed, which is an unacceptable error for my use case.

Do I have any other options to build a DataFrame like this (with integer data, and with new columns being added dynamically - which will result with missing/undefined/NaN values), such that it works with integers internally? (or maybe work with other datatypes internally, as long as I don't lose integer precision?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `Int64`, you can convert your dictionary into series with that dtype:

```
# initialize dataframe with one column
test_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["time"])

# append many times, create a function
def append(df, d):
    return df.append(pd.Series(d, dtype='Int64'), ignore_index=True)

# "append column" - add data with a newly defined column
test_df = append(test_df, {'time': 20, 'varA': 14})

# (same)
test_df = append(test_df, {'time': 5673547, 'varB': 78})

# (same)
test_df = append(test_df, {'time': 9480530495459073, 'varC': 4567457})
```

Output:

```
               time  varA  varB     varC
0                20    14   NaN      NaN
1           5673547  <NA>    78      NaN
2  9480530495459073  <NA>  <NA>  4567457
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @QuangHoang - I saw pd.Series in diverse posts I found related to this, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my use case; and your answer explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does appending it as actual dataframes solve your problem?  Optionally pass dtype='int' in your original test_df if you want to prevent them from being objects.

```
import pandas as pd
print("pandas.__version__ {}".format(pd.__version__))

# initialize dataframe with one column
test_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["time"])

# "append column" - add data with a newly defined column
test_df = test_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'time': [20], 'varA': [14]}), ignore_index=True)

# # (same)
test_df = test_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'time': [5673547], 'varB': [78]}), ignore_index=True)

# # (same)
test_df = test_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'time': [9480530495459073], 'varC': [4567457]}), ignore_index=True)

print(test_df)
print(test_df.astype(pd.Int64Dtype()))

pandas.__version__ 1.0.1
               time  varA  varB       varC
0                20  14.0   NaN        NaN
1           5673547   NaN  78.0        NaN
2  9480530495459073   NaN   NaN        4567457.0
               time  varA  varB     varC
0                20    14  <NA>     <NA>
1           5673547  <NA>    78     <NA>
2  9480530495459073  <NA>  <NA>     4567457
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris - I guess it doesn't really, because as it can be seen from your printout, `test_df` is still internally float (though, `time` column seemingly isn't, and it is integer), which means there is still possible loss of precision  when you cast to pd.Int64Dtype (though, interestingly, your printout of `time` column shows the correct 9480530495459073 - but maybe that is because just the `time` column here is internally int; ... ah, it is probably because `time` column does not have NaNs here!).